# How can I synchronize Node and Yarn versions in my nix shell?

Tags: yarnpkg, nix, replit

I have the following `replit.nix` file:

```hs
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.nodejs-17_x
        pkgs.nodePackages.yarn
    ];
}
```

`node -v` returns 17.3.1, but `yarn node -v` returns `14.18.3`. I was able to find a [corresponding NIX issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/145634), but I am unsure about how to properly set the overlays accordingly. How can I set up my configuration file to synchronize my NodeJS version and my yarn NodeJS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override yarn with a null nodejs value (this also means it can't be a `nodePackage`):

```hs
{ pkgs }: {
    deps = [
        pkgs.nodejs-17_x
        (pkgs.yarn.override {
          nodejs = null;
        })
    ];
}
```